# Customizing Card.Header with React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

How do I style Card.Header when it's passed in as a prop to Accordion.Toggle? For example, I don't know how to make "Click Me" bold.

```
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
        <Card>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
            Click me!
            </Accordion.Toggle>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>Text</Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
        <Card border="secondary">
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1">
            Click me!
            </Accordion.Toggle>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
            <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
    </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the normal inline style would be fine

```
<Accordion>
  <Card>
     <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0" style={{color: 'red'}}>
  ...
```

You can also build a customized component with it, refer related document: [custom-toggle](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/accordion/#custom-toggle)

---

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
        <Card>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0" style={{color: 'red'}}>
            Click me!
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>Text</Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
        <Card border="secondary">
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1">
            Click me!
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
            <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding bold html tags?

```
<b> Click me! </b> 

<b></b>
```